# Possible in DocPad? `@document.someMetaProperty.renderAsMarkdown()`

Tags: docpad

I have a document which contains some metadata in the form of small markdown snippets.
Inside of a layout, I want to grab them, render them from markdown to HTML, and then print out the results.  (I’m using DocPad’s default template engine, “Eco”.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to do. Docpad will automatically render markdown as html (well - if you have the docpad plugin "docpad-plugin-marked" installed). I would normally think of markdown as the default "template" engine

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you are using `marked` as your Markdown engine.  If you are using RoboSkirt or something else, you can do something similar, just adapt to use their module instead.

First, make sure you have the `marked` node module in your top level project:

```
npm install --save marked
```

Then add a helper function to your docpad.coffee that makes the `marked` function available in templates:

```
docpadConfig = {
    templateData:
        # Specify some site properties
        marked: require('marked')
}
```

Now you can use this in your .eco files:

```
<div>
    <%- @marked(@document.someMetaProperty) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to Erv's answer is to use the **Docpad Api** which let's you pass the text through its render workflow (this way you can use other installed template engines too)

```
var renderOpts = {
    text: 'here is some **markdown**',
    filename:'markdown',
    renderSingleExtensions:true
};
docpadInstance.action('render', renderOpts, function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

source for above snippet: http://docpad.org/docs/api#rendering-individual-files